# How to handle authentication popup on Safari browser using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, authentication, selenium-webdriver, safari

[image]

I get an authentication popup on Safari browser when I try to connect to one of my internal website https://staging.toyota.com and I have written the below custom function using Robot class to enter the authentication credentials

```
private static void loginTier1(String value) {
        System.out.println("I was called!!!");
        try {
            Robot r = new Robot();
            r.delay(6000);
            System.out.println("Inside loginTier1");
            for(char c : value.toCharArray()){
                if(c=='_') {
                    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
                    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
                    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                }else if(c=='%') {
                    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_5);
                    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_5);
                    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                }else if(c=='$') {
                    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_4);
                    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_4);
                    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                }else if(c=='!') {
                    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
                    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_1);
                    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                }
                else {
                    if(Character.isAlphabetic(c) && Character.isUpperCase(c))
                        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(c));
                    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(c));
                    if(Character.isAlphabetic(c) && Character.isUpperCase(c))
                        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
                };

            }
        }catch(AWTException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("robot fail: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

But during execution, Safari browser is not accepting the KeyPress event and is blocked with the below screenshot

[image]

Could you please help me on how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you really limited to Safari?

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 I automated all the other browsers.